# Get items from taskmanager details listview

Tags: c++, windows, listview, winapi, taskmanager

I tried to get the list of items in taskmanager's listview under the tab `details`.

I could get most information such as items count using `ListView_GetItemCount(hwnd)` (a winapi method) it returned `260` which is the list of processes in taskmanager listview, and could also get headers count using `ListView_GetColumn(hwnd)` successfully.

but when I try to get the text of the items, or search by string, or get text on a specific index of item or column, it just returns empty string.

```
ListView_GetItem(hwnd, pitem)
```

what is the problem? is it protected not to show only the text? because I could get everything else. what method can I use to get the text?

[image]

Comment: `ListView_GetItem` take **address**. you from what process do this ? if not from process, where listview located - this of course will be not work. and main - what sense try do this ?

Comment: I am passing the `hwnd`, and can already access the list item count and other properties except the text

Comment: Wrong solution to the problem surely. Why don't you use the API to get the info?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I was planning to select and manipulate the taskmanager list itself based on PID for testing purpose

Answer (score 1):

`ListView_...()` macros/`LVM_...` messages that carry structure pointers, like `LVITEM*`, can't marshal those structs across process boundaries.  Those macros/messages are meant to be used only in the same process that owns the ListView.  So, you would have to remotely allocate an `LVITEM` within the TaskManager process using `VirtualAllocEx()`, issue `ListView_GetItem()` to fill that memory, and then marshal that data back to your own process using `ReadProcessMemory()`.  Needless to say, that is not likely to be allowed for a system component like TaskManager.

You should try using [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32) interfaces instead.  It was designed for this kind of work.

Comment: I can already get the count of the items through, I am running as admin. it's only the text content that is being a trouble

Comment: Getting the count is easy, since it is just an integer that can be carried directly in the message's return value.  But marshaling the actual data across process boundaries requires more work.

Comment: I can delete items, even clear the view. injecting raises problems with the antiviruses

Comment: Again, because those kind of operations are carrying only simple integers directly in the message parameters, they DON'T carry pointers to data structures that would have to cross over the process boundary. You don't seem to be grasping this concept.

Comment: thank you , seems I have have to give up, since can't be done without injection.

Comment: @Abraham: You actually have quite a bit of choice. Depending on which columns you want, it may be easier to retrieve it more directly, rather than via Task Manager.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I was planning to select and manipulate the list itself based on PID for testing purpose.

Comment: @Abraham You do have a choice. I even gave you one alternative - UI Automation.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thank you! I can't wait to check it out if that does allow this.